# Why am I getting `none` as the output?

Tags: python, encryption

I am making a Caesar Cipher encryption code for homework. I think I typed everything I needed to write.
However I do have an issue.

I am getting `none` in the code:

```
def fancy_caesar(message, keyword, true_false_statement):
    count = 0
    while count == 0:
        true_false_statement = str(input("Type True if you want to encrypt.\nType false if you want to decrypt: "))
        if true_false_statement == 'true' or true_false_statement == 'True' or true_false_statement == 't' or true_false_statement == 'T':
            count = count + 1
        elif true_false_statement == 'false' or true_false_statement == 'False' or true_false_statement == 'F' or true_false_statement == 'f':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print('None')
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    translated_message = ""
    keyword_index = 0

    for character in message:
        if character in alphabet:
            number = alphabet.find(character)
            if true_false_statement == 'true' or true_false_statement == 'True' or true_false_statement == 't' or true_false_statement == 'T':
                number = number + (ord(keyword[keyword_index]) - ord('a'))
            elif true_false_statement == 'false' or true_false_statement == 'False' or true_false_statement == 'F' or true_false_statement == 'f':
                number = number - (ord(keyword[keyword_index])) - ord('a')
            keyword_index += 1
            keyword_index = keyword_index % len(keyword)

            if number >= len(alphabet):
                number = number - len(alphabet)
            elif number < 0:
                number = number + len(alphabet)
            translated_message = translated_message + alphabet[number]
        else:
            translated_message = translated_message + character
            return translated_message

def main():
    message = input("Enter string you want to encrypt/decrypt: ")
    keyword = input('Keyword for encryption: ')            
    true_false_statement = ''
    translated_message = fancy_caesar(message, keyword,true_false_statement)
    print(translated_message)

main()
```

When I enter the `message` input 'sloth,' I get `none` instead of 'tlruh'.

Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Try entering the message `sloth!` (with the exclamation point at the end).  Does it work now?  What about if you try the message `cute sloth`?

Comment: It works with the exclamation point in the end. what do I need to do to change it? I end up getting the output I want but with the exclamation at the end which I don't want.

Comment: The provided code will not run. Please provide code that runs and reproduces the error. One way to test the code you provide is to copy it back from the question once you post it and try to run it.

Comment: For debugging help in the future, you need to make a [mre] including minimal code. Most of the code here is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you added `return translated_message` inside `else` block (statement above `def main()`).

Move the statement to align with `for` statement, you will get desired output.